# Android Studio debug invoked method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Is there a way to debug an invoked method?

I am calling this method, but there isn't any error thrown.

[Class Reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.java): 
Method: `public boolean disconnect(BluetoothDevice device)`

The dispatched result is `false`. For that reason either of one of these lines must have been executed and dispatched the Boolean value. I expect `service.disconnect(device)` was called and returned `false`, but I want to prove it.

```kotlin
try {
   [...]
   if (service != null && isEnabled() && isValidDevice(device)) {
      return service.disconnect(device);
   }
   if (service == null) Log.w(TAG, "Proxy not attached to service");
   return false;
} catch (RemoteException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Stack:" + Log.getStackTraceString(new Throwable()));
   return false;
}
```

The `BluetoothA2dp.disconnect()` is invoked by this code

```kotlin
private fun disconnect(context: Context, device: BluetoothDevice) {
  val serviceListener: ServiceListener = object : ServiceListener {
    override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
      try {
        val disconnectMethod = BluetoothA2dp::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("disconnect", BluetoothDevice::class.java)
        disconnectMethod.isAccessible = true
        val cReturn = disconnectMethod.invoke(proxy, device) as Boolean
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
          error("disconnectMethod", ex)
        } finally {
          bluetoothAdapter!!.closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy)
        }
      }
      override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {}
    }
  bluetoothAdapter!!.getProfileProxy(context, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.A2DP)
}
```

Fabrizio's way:

The overlay is sadly hidden, but I clicked **step in**

[Youtube-Video](https://youtu.be/1Zscdr6Prrs?t=9)

Answer (score -1):

While in debug, you have some controls to jump into method calls.
You can see them by going to "Run -> Debugging actions".

You can put a break point on your method call so when you run the debug it will stop there, then you can press F7 to jump into the method call and see what happens inside:

[image: Breakpoint]

Comment: Yes right, it's basic debugging, but how you debug a method which is called invoked

Comment: please look the provided video

Comment: Hi @GreilOmatics it seems you have to Clean build and Rebuild